# Verificação de variável se o campo não for digitado em Python?

Tags: python

eu preciso verificar se o variável foi preenchida com um nome, eu tentei verificar com If e com break porém o campo continua preenchendo sem digitar alguma palavra....Abaixo está o código que estou fazendo...

```
opcao = 0
while opcao != 6:
    print("""\033[32m
Em relação aos contatos do sistema, você deseja...

    1 - Inserir
    2 - Buscar
    3 - Listar
    4 - Alterar
    5 - Excluir
    6 - Voltar
\033[0;0m""")

    opcao = int(input("\033[32mInforme a opção desejada: \033[0;0m"))

    if opcao == 1:
        print("\n\033[47m\033[30m--- Digite os dados do contato ---\033[0;0m\n")

        n = input("Nome: ")
        t = input("Telefone: ")
        e = input("E-mail: ")
        i = int(input("Id: "))

        if n == "":
            print("\n\033[47m\033[30mEspaço vazio! Digite um nome...\033[0;0m")

        if t == "":
            print("\n\033[47m\033[30mEspaço vazio! Digite um login...\033[0;0m")

        if e == "":
            print("\n\033[47m\033[30mEspaço vazio! Digite um senha...\033[0;0m")

        print("\n\033[47m\033[30m--- Contato inserido com sucesso ---\033[0;0m\n")

        inserir_contato(conexao, n, t, e, i)
```

Comment: Em que parte do código você usou o `break`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você imprimiu a mensagem

```
print("\n\033[47m\033[30mEspaço vazio! Digite um nome...\033[0;0m")
```

Porém o código continua rodando e insere o nome vazio mesmo assim! Você só pode inserir o nome se estiver preenchido.

Uma forma é usar o `break` como você falou, mas essa palavra-chave só funciona dentro de um bloco de repetição como `for` ou `while`:

```
while True: 
    n = input("Nome: ")
    if n == "":
        print("\n\033[47m\033[30mEspaço vazio! Digite um nome...\033[0;0m")
    else:
        break
```

Dessa forma a estrutura vai repetir infinitamente (`while True`) e só vai parar quando chegar no `break`, nesse caso, se o usuário não deixar o campo em branco (`else`).

Em outras palavras: se o usuário deixar o campo em branco, será impressa a mensagem de erro e o código vai repetir, até que o usuário digite um nome, fazendo com que o código saia da repetição através do `break`.

Comment: Entendi, dessa forma eu já faço as variáveis n, t, e, i dentro do while com a verificação e não separado como eu fiz é isso?

Comment: A finalidade do comando `while` é repetir uma parte do código. Você tem que colocar dentro do `while` tudo que você quer repetir. Se você fizer um `while` só, e o usuário errar na última pergunta, o python vai repetir o `while` inteiro, ou seja, todas as perguntas que estão dentro do `while` vão aparecer de novo. Então é recomendado fazer um `while` separado pra cada pergunta… Assim se o usuário errar uma pergunta, o sistema mostra a mensagem de erro e repete somente aquela pergunta. Futuramente ao aprender mais você pode fazer uma função para não ter que escrever o mesmo código várias vezes.